# GAINING ACCESS TO /System/bin/sh WITHOUT Rooting device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to gain root access to an android device and every time I run `adb root` or `adb su` i get an error `/system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found`.

I want to be able to access this folder without actually having to root the device. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: which folder are you talking about? `/system/bin` ?

Comment: @Lino 
`/system/bin/sh` to be specific

This is the error I get 
`/system/bin/sh: ls-: inaccessible or not found`

Comment: `sh` is a command that is stored in the `/system/bin` folder. So it is normal that the folder `/system/bin/sh` doesn't exist. Also, the error you've reported in the last comment is saying that the command `ls-` doesn't exist, and that's normal as well. I suggest you to take a look at how the bash commands works especially in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your environment for building Android devices by running the following command from the root of your source code checkout:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```